# Prove by induction $ 1+3+\dots+(2n-1)=n^2 \forall n\in \Bbb N_1 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I need help with this exercise.
What I've done so far is:

1st: Prove it with $n = 1$ (for example):

> $$ (2\times1-1) = 1^2 $$
>   $$ 1 = 1 $$

which is true

2nd: if $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n+1)$ should be true as well.
So now I substitute $n$ for $m+1$

> $$ n = m+1\\
> \text{and}\\
> P(n) \implies P(m+1) $$
>
> Therefore:
>
> $$1+3+\dots+(2(m+1)-1) = (m+1)^2 \\
> 1+3+\dots+(2m+2-1) = (m+1)^2 \\
> 1+3+\dots+(2m+1) = m^2+1+2m $$

Now, the problem is that I don't know how to prove it/conclude the exercise.
Could someone help me please?
Thank you so much

If something's not very clear, please let me know. I'll try to explain again

Comment: Well, all that's left is to show $(m+1)^2=m^2+1+2m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done it right, but:
$$(a+b)^2+a^2+2ab+b^2$$
So:
$$(m+1)^2=m^2+2m+1 \neq m^2+1+2$$
So, you've assumed that it's true for $n=m$, so:
$$1+3+\dots+(2m-1)=m^2$$
For $n=m+1$, you've shown it:
$$1+3+\dots+(2m+1) = m^2+1+2m $$
Now after using some more brackets and writing out more terms:
$$[1+3+\dots + (2m-1)]+(2m+1) = [m^2]+(1+2m) $$
The parts in the [] brackets are equal because of the assumption, and the only thing left to prove is that $2m+1=2m+1$, which is true.

Comment: I think OP missed an $m$ in $2m$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Yes, that's what I wanted to point out for him.

Comment: But you've multiplied an extra $m$ in your answer :)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Yes, that was a mistake made by me :)

Comment: @Agapita I'd suggest you to use either $n$ and $n+1$ or $m$ and $m+1$, but not $n$ and $m+1$ at the same time. I like to 'find' the $P(n)$ in the $P(n+1)$, that's why I did it this way. But it's not better than adding $2n+1$ to both sides, and realizing that $n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$. It's really just up to you which way do you like to do it, I think.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I got it :) .Do you think that for these types of exercises it is better to put first the assumption made at the begging and then add the 'm+1'? Like you did in this example? So that you can see what changes and what doesn't and figure out if P(n) really leads to P(m+1)? @Botond

Answer (score 3):

Your setup of the induction step is incorrect. You must *prove* that the implication $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ is true, so it is logically incorrect to *assume* that this implication is true as you seem to have done. It's very important to keep track in your head at all points of the proof: which equation is *known* to be true, and which equation you *must prove* is true.

To prove $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$, you assume that $P(n)$ is true. That is, you may *assume* that this equation is true:
$$1 + 3 + \cdots + (2n-1) = n^2
$$
is true. Using that assumption, you *must prove* that this equation is true:
$$1 + 3 + \cdots + (2n-1) + (2n+1) = (n+1)^2
$$
To do that, make a substitution and do some algebra:
\begin{align*}
1 + 3 + \cdots + (2n-1) + (2n+1) &= \underbrace{1 + 3 + \cdots + (2n-1)}_{=n^2} + (2n+1)  \\
  &= n^2 + 2n + 1 \\
  &= (n+1)^2
\end{align*}

Comment: @Agapita Make sure to check this answer too. It's a bit different way of mine, but it might fit better to your way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

$$1+3+...+(2m+1) = \Big[1+3+...+(2m-1)\Big]+(2m+1)=m^2+(2m +1) =...$$

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it! Just a small mistake in the last step. You should note that
\begin{align*}
 1+3+...+(2m+1) = \underbrace{1+3+...+ (2m-3) + (2m-1)}_{\text{induction hypothesis!}} + (2m+1) = m^2 + (2m+1)
\end{align*}
Finally, 
$$
m^2+2m+1 = (m+1)^2
$$
so you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $n=m+1$:

$$1+3+\cdots+(2m-1)+(2(m+1)-1)=m^2+2m+2-1=(m+1)^2$$ so $P(m+1)$ holds.

Hence by Mathematical Induction, the result is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $P(n)$ is true and try to prove $P(n+1)$ to holds. 
$1+3+...+ 2n-1=n^2$ by the induction hypothesis, and now let's add the next odd number to the equation: $1+3+...+2n-1+2(n+1)-1=n^2+2n+1$
The expression on the right-hand side can be rewritten as $(n+1)^2$ and therefore the formula holds.